# How to access WEB API on .NET Core from the outside network?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to access my API from the outside ?

On the local machine I access my API like this:

```
https://localhost:44377/api/stations
```

So my IP address for example is: `186.143.119.43`

What do I need to change to see it through external networks?

This is my `launchSettings.json` file:

```
    {
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51429",
      "sslPort": 44377
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How to access this API from outside network ?**

Comment: define 'outside'? is this your home network? You companies?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default binding of the Kestral web server only binds to the `localhost`, and it is not be allowed for the public access. However, you can override this setting by sending a custom URL value from the command line:

> `dotnet run --urls http://0.0.0.0:8080`

You can also configure the custom URL value directly in the `Program.cs` file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:8080")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
 }
```

p.s. The above approaches work only when your firewall allows access to the configured TCP port(8080).

Comment: Hey, I use this code and I access the API with my IP from the local network, but I can't access the API from the outside (other) network.

Comment: If you try to access it from an external network, all your requests will be sent to your router. So, you should configure your router in such a way that it forwards the incoming requests to your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

If its for testing purposes consider using an service like ngrok.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your ports and your IP in the rooter Idk how to do it but I early do it for a server for one of my game or you can use NGROK (I use it for temporary servers)

Answer (score 0):

As @Suky Laplante and @Nisd already answered you can use Ngrok. Setting up and installing everything you need will take 5 minutes. This is the fastest and easiest solution I have found. I will also add a link to video tutorial, which may be useful to beginners.

[youtube video Ngrok tutorial step by step](https://youtu.be/KcbUaZ2a4hc)